# How to drive a battery-powered heating element with temperature feedback control

Tags: microcontroller, transistors, switches, heat

### Preface (not necessary to answer question)

I am not an electrical engineering student, so I am very far out of my element. However, I do have to complete this part of the project and am having a lot of difficulty doing so on my own. So, please feel free to educate me like I'm 5. I have some rudimentary knowledge of electronics but the depth isn't there for me. Please also link me to additional resources you think may be helpful for me to continue pursuing this problem on my own.

### Problem Statement

Using a microcontroller (Arduino/ATTiny), drive power to a heating element based on the element's current temperature, with a target temperature of 40 C.

**Relevant Info and Constraints**

- The heating element is a small coil of nichrome wire.
- The production-level PCB must fit within a circle of a diameter of < 30 mm.
- The height of the production-level PCB must be thin to fit within the form factor of the device it will be placed into.
- The heating element must not exceed 40 C, and should have power cut off when it reaches the setpoint.
- The production-level PCB will be coated in an epoxy such that the circuit is safe from extremely humid environments as well as **storage** temperatures up to 125 C (*not* operating temperatures), however the heating element will be connected outside of the epoxy puck.

I have below a (very) rough schematic. For now, I am not too concerned about values of components, but more concerned about what components I need to make this work. I am reasonably confident I can work out the math once I know what I should be working with.

[image]

Description of what I *intended* for the above circuit to accomplish:

> Current flows to the MCU powered by the Vin pin and grounded to the negative terminal of the battery. The MCU is in parallel with the heating element, and transmits a PWM signal to an optocoupler acting as the gatekeeper for power to the heating element. The temperature of the heating element is read into the input of the MCU by a currently unknown method for measuring its temperature, and this temperature is used to influence the duty cycle of the PWM signal. As the temperature nears the setpoint, the duty cycle decreases, and is at 0% upon reaching the setpoint temperature.

### Questions

- **Green Question Mark** Do I need to galvanically isolate the MCU from the heating element, or is the current connection setup okay? If it needs to be isolated, how would I accomplish this since the battery is the sole power source of the device?
- **Pink Question Mark** Should I include an additional resistor here? What about a voltage amplifier and/or regulator?
- **Red Question Mark** Should I use an NTC/PTC thermistor to measure the temperature of the element? A thermocouple? Or something else? How would I wire it the above schematic?
- Would a MOSFET be better than an optocoupler here? Or a BJT? Or is an optocoupler a suitable switching method?
- I want there to be some sort of thermal failsafe, similar to a circuit breaker, that will cutoff the circuit entirely in the potential event that the heating element gets too hot and isn't being controlled by the MCU. I looked into fuses, but the issue is that the device will be subject to temperatures of 115 C plus in some situations, and think the fuse would melt and break the circuit after simply being in the environment despite not overheating. What are other solutions that might accomplish this?
- Are there ICs that do what I am trying to do here that can simplify my design? Are there better solutions I should pursue that fit within my constraints?

Comment: An optocoupler wastes power and the reason you're willing to waste that power is for isolation, but you're using it to isolate a circuit from itself, which as far as I can see is pointless and a mosfet would be nicer.  Your MCU may require voltage regulation on it's input.  It's specs will tell you, but in general heating elements run enough current to vary your battery output voltage significantly, which brings me to R2.  If R2 represents your battery/line resistance then it makes sense, but adding resistance in that part of the circuit intentionally is a bad idea.

Comment: As far as adding temperature sense you could at least get started by deciding how fast you need your circuit to respond and you know your temperature range so you can probably decide what sensor type is adequate and then look at it's output to decide what you need to interface it with the MCU *and calibrate it*.  I'm only a novice though so I can only see how to break it down into smaller tasks.  I've never designed anything like this myself.  They sure don't give you much space but I guess surface mount stuff is tiny so maybe it's realistic.

Comment: @KH Thank you! I'll nix the optocoupler and R2. To clarify, you meant to add a voltage regulator prior to the Vin pin of the MCU? Yes, the expectations are a little high for the constraints, I agree.. unfortunately not mine to decide.

Comment: I can't guarantee it's necessary, but I know MCUs and logic circuits can fail or misperform with out of spec input voltage, and in general heaters are high power loads compared to logic circuits and can cause variation in your input voltage(although they're not specifically requiring you to PWM the heater coil, it's not clear from the requirements whether the circuit is intended to shut down or oscillate once it hits 40 degrees.  The microcontroller is likely a small enough load you can get away with a tiny linear regulator.  Raw dogging the battery voltage through the heating coil is fine.

Comment: You can also settle on a microcontroller since you know how many inputs and outputs you need and look at the recommended circuits for it to figure out what you need for caps, etc.  I also see no purpose to the switch with 3 LEDs in line.  The LEDs will tell you the switch is closed, but the switch won't do anything.

Comment: At any rate you might want to take the tour.  Certain types of general and shopping questions are banned, and questions for school like yours require an effort proportional to the course requirements and the answers you want.  This is a good start, but you should keep updating it and showing the work you're putting in to reduce what you're asking for to specifics that people can help you with without doing your project for you.  Another hint on fuses, there's probably a fuse for the job, regardless of your temperatures, ETC.

Comment: You would normally use a n chan mosfet to switch the 0V side of the heater. As for sensing the temperature, a ntc is reasonable. How to do it? I’m sure someone has done an example for Arduino. Besides, it sounds like your making a vape. Plenty of examples just a Google away. As for thermal protection, there’s thermal fuses - just don’t try soldering them! Why?

Comment: As far as adding a safety factor *when the MCU is dead and all your thinking power is gone*, you could have the default operation be to drive the heating coil with say a 30% duty cycle PWM to limit current to it.  If the MCU fails and the switch remains on, current will be much higher and you should be able to use the difference to trigger a fuse.  Key is to look at the requirement (MCU fails ON) and figure out how you can differentiate that from normal operation without using digital logic.  The solution may be to redefine normal operation a bit.

Comment: Because you're potting, a fuse blowing inside the potting compound can't be easily replaced, so you'd want to be conscious that a shorted output would blow your fuse as well unless you detect ON state output current, so that's one more thing you could add in to be fancy.  This way the MCU protects the circuit from burnout from a bad coil or short, and the permanent fuse only blows in case of MCU failure, although there are probably additional challenges like making sure current rise time in a dead short is slow enough that the chip can shut down fast enough.

Comment: @KH The LED's are manual switch operation to provide illumination when the user flips the switch. I actually had R2 in the circuit thinking it would prevent the circuit from shorting when the switch to the LEDs was flipped on. I did try to avoid general shopping Qs and tried to focus more on the substance of how it works. This is less of a routine assignment and more of a freelance project. I will look to update the post as I continue to learn more! First I will figure out how to get the feedback control to work prior to adding failure controls haha.

Comment: @Kartman Hahaha ironically very similar, but definitely not a vape! It's a device to warm special surfaces in humid environments and ecosystems. I will look more into NTC solutions, thank you! For the N-channel MOSFET, should I drive it with a transistor from the PWM? Or is there no need for that since the voltages are small? Can you elaborate more on your comment about thermal fuses? I'm not sure I understand.

Comment: MCU seems like problematic overkill, unless the circuit has to do intersting things like a programmable or variable temperature. What's the temperature tolerance? What's the variation in heat output required for various ambients? A simple thermistor and opamp would be easier and have far fewer failure mechanisms. Your present requirements for power output versus temperature are both incomplete and contradictory. You should plot a graph of power versus temperature to clarify that specification, it may involve time as well if a PID loop is being used.

Comment: @Neil_UK Originally I had thought of a purely analog circuit but couldn't come up with how to realize it. I also worried it would be hard to put through quality control testing and calibration without a 'modifiable' parameter like an MCU's code can provide. Are these concerns valid? I apologize for the incomplete parameters - however I'm not too concerned with power yet, first I want a working circuit, even if it doesn't reach 40C, and can change the pieces to fit after. The goal is to get a functional circuit first, and adapt the pieces and values after. Is this an okay approach?